# lambda function does not get triggered unless there's a change in code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an S3 putObject event trigger to run my lambda function. However, if there's no code change in the lambda function as compared to the previous run, nothing new shows up in the cloud watch whenever I upload a new S3 file. Is this normal behaviour? How can I ensure that the function always runs with a new upload?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I would guess that something is wrong in your trigger. Are you sure the trigger is setup on the correct bucket? i.e. It's not setup on the lambda code bucket by mistake, is it?

Comment: what do you mean by "lambda code bucket". The bucket is in S3 and the lambda function script is not present anywhere in S3 @DanielScott

Comment: Can you clarify what s3 putObject has to do with changing the source code of your lambda function?

Comment: @x89, you have to upload your lambda code somewhere in S3, although it's possible that whatever deployment method you're using is hiding this from you. My theory is that you may have your S3 event trigger setup to trigger when the code is uploaded to this bucket, instead of the other bucket.

Comment: +1 on @DanielScott's idea - the only way this would happen is if the trigger was on the S3 bucket hosting the Lambda code and not the intended bucket. x89, can you please share how you're creating the event trigger programatically (terraform code? CDK? CloudFormation?) or how it looks like inside the console if you're doing it manually?

Comment: I created the trigger on S3 manually. I added the screenshot. How do I know where my lambda function is being stored on s3? Is it automatic? Because I separately created a lambda function on the console @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Hmm - if you used the console to upload the code (without specifying an S3 bucket yourself) when you create the Lambda function, then AWS has stored your code in a private S3 location that you have no access to...

Comment: @x89 How are you adding the file to the bucket? Via the SDK or uploading via the UI? I suspect it may be your event type that's not encompassing all of the ways of "uploading" a file and you're just observing some alternate behaviour related to something else

Comment: Yes, I just upload via the console'S UI. The trigger works if there's a difference in the lambda function's code. However, if there's no change in the code and the new uploaded file is also the same as the one uploaded before (even tho it was deleted first), then the function does not re-run. So maybe it is triggered...but it just doesn't run? @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: @DanielScott I added a screenshot

Comment: @x89 Also add `s3:ObjectCreated:Post` to the S3 event notification in addition to `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` and test again

Comment: @x89 Did that work?